# How to separate numbers and letters from letters in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2.3trillion', '9', '3.4trillion'],
                         'B': ['8', '1.2trillion', '3trillion'],
                         'C': ['0.1trillion', '12', '2trillion'], 
                         'D': ['42trillion', '52trillion','trillion']})

print(df)
```

The contents of the question were made into a picture file.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using [regex](https://realpython.com/regex-python/)?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for generate 2 new columns:

```
for x in df.columns:
    df[[f'num_{x}', f'text_{x}']] = df[x].str.extract(r'(\d*\.*\d*)(\D*)')

print(df)
             A            B            C           D num_A    text_A num_B  \
0  2.3trillion            8  0.1trillion  42trillion   2.3  trillion     8   
1            9  1.2trillion           12  52trillion     9             1.2   
2  3.4trillion    3trillion    2trillion    trillion   3.4  trillion     3   

     text_B num_C    text_C num_D    text_D  
0             0.1  trillion    42  trillion  
1  trillion    12              52  trillion  
2  trillion     2  trillion        trillion
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.extract` to separate the numbers and letters in the dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2.3trillion', '9', '3.4trillion'],
                   'B': ['8', '1.2trillion', '3trillion'],
                   'C': ['0.1trillion', '12', '2trillion'], 
                   'D': ['42trillion', '52trillion','trillion']})
    
for column in df.columns:
    df[column+"_num"] = df[column].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)', expand=False)
    df[column+"_text"] = df[column].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False)

print(df)
```

`(\d+\.?\d*)` - for integer or floats. If you want only integers: `(\d+)`

`expand=False` → return type is `Series`. `expand=True` → return type is a `DataFrame`

You can also use [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) function

Answer (score 0):

you can use re to parse the number and the str in column

```
import pandas as pd
import re


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2.3trillion', '9', '3.4trillion'],
                   'B': ['8', '1.2trillion', '3trillion'],
                   'C': ['0.1trillion', '12', '2trillion'],
                   'D': ['42trillion', '52trillion', 'trillion']})
def get_num(x):
    res = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\d+', x)
    if len(res) > 0:
        return res[0]
    else:
        return 0


def get_str(x):
    res = re.findall(r'\D+$', x)
    if len(res) > 0:
        return res[0]
    else:
        return ""


for c in df.columns:
    df[c + "_1"] = df[c].apply(get_num)
    df[c + "_2"] = df[c].apply(get_str)
print(df)
```